# Alternating left and right positioning with CSS

Tags: css

So using PHP I am displaying a page of images.  I have a div tag for containing these pictures.

What Im trying to do, is alternate positioning these images on the left and right side of the browser.

So entry 1 is positioned on the left
scrolling down
entry 2 is positioned on the right
etc.

If my div container is `style="position:relative;width=100%"`
How do I make my images alternate hugging the left and side of the browser?

Comment: It seems like all the answers are giving me solutions where left image and right image are on the same horizontal line - but Im looking for image on left, than scroll down, then image on right, etc.

Comment: The clear:left and clear:right parts of those solutions should make them line vertically rather than horizontally.

Answer (score 9):

There are several possible ways, one would be the following:

CSS:

```css
div img{
 float:left;  
 clear:both;    
}
div img:nth-of-type(2n){
  float:right;
}
```

Check the **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/sgp6b/)**

If you dont want them alternate that way, use

```css
div img{
 float:left;  
 clear:left;    
}
div img:nth-of-type(2n){
  float:right; 
  clear:right;
}
```

Depending on the browsers you have to support (Internet Explorer 8 and lower don't support that selector), use a class on all even images and replace `:nth-of-type(2n)` with that class.

Comment: I was just going to suggest this. CSS only solution is my preferred approach for any alternating styling rules.

Comment: @Ralph you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left to indicate to the Stackoverflow Community that your problem has been solved.

Comment: Good solution, beware though: nth-of-type requires IE9 or higher.

Comment: @Faust Hence my note on the support in the last sentence.

Comment: @Christoph Your fiddle doesn't work anymore because it has an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

for the left-huggers:

```
style="float:left;clear:left;"
```

and for the right-huggers

```
style="float:right;clear:right;"
```

...though if your container is not wide enough to fit more than 2 images across, you won't need the "clear" declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Set `float: left;` when `index%2 == 0` and `float: right;` when `index%2==1`
`index` being an index variable of a loop iterating over your images.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein to the other answers

```
div img:nth-child(even) { float: right; clear: right; }
div img:nth-child(odd) { float: left; clear: left; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GL667/